flask api method response.body.getReader() and TextDecorder().decode method are truncating the response received from API
I have an flask API which is returning an HTML table.
sample resp is
{
  "type": "text", 
  "content": "<table border=\"1\" class=\"dataframe table table-striped\">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style=\"text-align: right;\">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>Business Group</th>\n          <th>Person Type</th>\n      <th>Date of Birth</th>\n      <th>Hire Date</th>\n      <th>Tenure</th>\n      <th>Job Name</th>\n      <th>Job Level</th>\n      <th>HR Business Partner</th>\n      <th>Country</th>\n      <th>Geo</th>\n      <th>Age</th>\n      <th>Gender</th>\n      <th>Grade Type</th>\n     </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>91</th>\n      <td>HR</td>\n       <td>Employee</td>\n      <td>1973-09-15</td>\n      <td>2020-06-09</td>\n      <td>4.257534</td>\n      <td>Product Designer</td>\n      <td>Manager</td>\n      <td>Luis Mendez</td>\n      <td>United States</td>\n      <td>Americas</td>\n      <td>51.021918</td>\n      <td>Female</td>\n      <td>3</td>\n     </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>"
}

I am reading this in HTML/JS using the below code block
then(response => {
  const reader = response.body.getReader();
  const decoder = new TextDecoder();
            
  return reader.read().then(function processText({ done, value }) {
    if (done) {
      hideSpinner();
      return;
    }
                
    const chunk = decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });

I am checking the chunk variable it is not giving me proper response. It shows value like this:
{"type": "text", "content": "<table border=\"1\" class=\"dataframe table table-striped\">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style=\"text-align: right;\">\n      <th></th>\n      
        <th>Business Group</th>\n          <th>Person Type</th>\n      <th>Date of Birth</th>\n      <th>Hire Date</th>\n      <th>Tenure</th>\n      <th>Job Name</th>\n      <th>Job Level</th>\n      <th>HR Business Partner</th>\n      <th>Country</th>\n      <th>Geo</th>\n      <th>Age</th>\n      <th>Gender</th>\n      <th>Grade Type</th>\n     </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>91</th>\n      <td>HR</td>\n       <td>Employee</td>\n      <td>1973-09-15</td>\n      <td>2020-06-09</td>\n      <td>4.257534</td>\n      <td>Product Designer</td>\n      <td>Manager</td>\n      <td>Luis Mendez</td>\n      <td>United States</td>\n      <td>Americas</td>\n      <td>51.021918</td>\n      <td>Female</td>\n      <td>3</td>\n

The response is truncated.  What can be done to rectify it?

It seems like your response is received as JSON. In my opinion you can use response.json() to read the object and then query the properties.

One clue is the name of a variable, chunk, which sounds like a chunk of the response not the entire response.

Is it?  Your code is very similar to this which is definitely using chunks.

The variable chunk does not contain the entire response.  You need to collect all chunks into one variable and only process it (json parse) once the done parameter is true.
